# How to properly handle NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to correctly handle NPE warnings.

Example:

```
@Nullable
LiveData<User> currentUser;

LiveData<List<Medication>> getUserMeds() {
    return parent.getMedsForUser(this.currentUser.getValue().getId());
}
```

Two NPE warnings are displayed for the methods

```
getValue()
getId()
```

I am currently making sure I don't mess outside of the function by checking for none null values but I would feel better having it implemented inside the function.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow the question... you could just explicitly compare `this.currentUser` with `null` before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It soley depends on what kind of logic you want to create.

### Explanation

The reason you get this warnings is that if one of those would return `null`, it would crash because you run into a situation like `null.method()`, which obviously cannot work.

---

### Annotations

You can use the annotations you already seem to be familiar with (`@Nullable` and `@NotNull`). Then your framework can ensure the correct property and you can rely on it.

---

### Handle yourself

You can also explicitly handle the case in your method, for example:

```
Value value = currentUser.getValue();
if (value == null) {
    // TODO Handle the case ...
}

Id id = value.getId();
if (id == null) {
    // TODO Handle the case ...
}

// They are now safe to use
```

---

### Note

But if you cannot really handle the case and would instead just crash with an exception, there is not really a benefit in handling it.

Note that `this` is obsolete in your code since you do not have a name clash between a field and a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

Perform a check before you return the value inside the function:

```java
LiveData<List<Medication>> getUserMeds() {
    if (this.currentUser == null) return "Some default value or throw an Exception"
    return parent.getMedsForUser(this.currentUser.getValue().getId());
}
```